# Obsfucated variable names

Tags: c#, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have code that has replaced function and variable names with Unicode symbols, like \u082. When exported as a project from DotPeek these aren't symbols, but strings like "\u082", thus preventing compiling in Visual Studio 2013. How to fix this issue without manually thinking up some name for everything?

Comment: Don't think of it as an issue (something broken) that must be fixed. This inconvenience has been put into place intentionally, to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Problem is it PREVENTS compiling. If I were able to compile it, it would've been enough.

Comment: @RomaValcer Maybe you didn't decompile it well.

Comment: Could you give advice on decompiling well to process those Unicode symbols?

Comment: I need a compile-able source code to make some minor editing.

Comment: Contact the authors of the assembly, they have the source code. And since they intentionally obfuscated their assembly, perhaps they will be happy to give you the source code…

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104588/obsfucated-variable-names#comment40910411_26104787

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of obfuscation is that the original names are lost.  You could attempt to write a program to make up names based on context, but this would be a fairly challenging endeavor.

In addition, most good obfuscators are going to do other things to the code to make it difficult to understand, possibly even introducing constructs that the runtime allows, but which crash less sophisticated decompilers.  Really, though, if you have the rights to use the source code, you should hopefully have access to an unobfuscated copy...

Comment: I mean, just some button to rename all those symbols (automatically) to some names, like pxx for variables, fxx for functions.

Comment: @RomaValcer, most likely there are tools that will do this, but I'm not personally familiar with them.  It's certainly possible to write such tools yourself, but it's not at all an easy job, especially if you want to deal with other obfuscator tricks that are deliberately trying to make your job difficult.  That said, it's quite unusual to wind up in a case where you have the legal right to modify the source, but don't have a copy of it.  If you are in such a position (such as having lost the source to a legacy product due to poor code archiving practices), then my condolences.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking at a deliberately obfuscated code that its owners preferred to hide its business logic/algorithms/security etc.

I can't think of an easy way to give the code members names some meaningful identity without to do it manually.

This is the goal of obfuscation process.

Comment: This obsfucation simply made code uncompilable. Only thing I need is to get it compileable.